# How should I dehydrate sage?

Tags: food-preservation, herbs

I have access to a dehydrator, but have never dehydrated sage. How should I dehydrate it?

Comment: Have you dehydrated other herbs?

Comment: just apples years ago

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sage dries well, I dry mine by cutting off whole branches and hanging them up in a dry, warm place for a week. Once dried I strip off the leaves by hand. However, if I had a dehydrator I'd strip the leaves off the branches and then stick them in the dehydrator until they're crispy. It's no more complex than that.

Comment: what should the settings be?

Comment: I have no idea @acoder, you haven't stated the type you are using and chances are I wouldn't know it anyway. The manual should suggest settings. If you don't have one it may be available online.

Comment: @acoder I usually do my herbs somewhere between 100 deg F and 130 deg F for about 24 hours. It will depend on the humidity. Sage leaves are pretty thick, so it may take two days at that temp. I would not be afraid of turning the temp up to even 150 for a while just because it will still be quite a bit more potent that any store-bought sage.